# Why I can't scrape this website even though the html content is visible?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests-html

[This is the link to scrape](https://www.bcorporation.net/en-us/find-a-b-corp/search/?refinement=countries%3DUnited%20Kingdom&refinement=countries%3DAustralia&refinement=countries%3DBelgium&refinement=countries%3DCanada&refinement=countries%3DChina&refinement=countries%3DDenmark&refinement=countries%3DFrance&refinement=countries%3DGermany&refinement=countries%3DIreland&refinement=countries%3DItaly&refinement=countries%3DNetherlands%20The&refinement=countries%3DMexico&refinement=countries%3DNew%20Zealand&refinement=countries%3DPortugal&refinement=countries%3DSpain&refinement=countries%3DSweden&refinement=countries%3DSwitzerland&refinement=countries%3DUnited%20States)

I don't know why but I can't scrape the data after the  which contains the entire data in this website.
I used requests_html and beautiful soup but there was no successful results :(
I just gave a basic code.

```
url = "https://www.bcorporation.net/en-us/find-a-b-corp/search?refinement=countries%3DUnited%20Kingdom&refinement=countries%3DAustralia&refinement=countries%3DBelgium&refinement=countries%3DCanada&refinement=countries%3DChina&refinement=countries%3DDenmark&refinement=countries%3DFrance&refinement=countries%3DGermany&refinement=countries%3DIreland&refinement=countries%3DItaly&refinement=countries%3DNetherlands%20The&refinement=countries%3DMexico&refinement=countries%3DNew%20Zealand&refinement=countries%3DPortugal&refinement=countries%3DSpain&refinement=countries%3DSweden&refinement=countries%3DSwitzerland&refinement=countries%3DUnited%20States"

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246 '
}

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
r.html.render(sleep=50, timeout=50)

content = r.html.find("ul")
title = r.html.find("div[data-testid = company_name]")
print(title)
```

Comment: The website appears to dynamically load much of its data/UI.  Just making a single HTTP request to that URL will only load the *initial* state of the page.  You'll likely either want to reverse-engineer what the page is doing and find where specifically you would get the data you want, or perhaps use more of a "headless browser" tool which would internally process the page's code and update the resulting DOM that you're interacting with.

Comment: Ohhh I understood David. I would try that

Answer (score 1):

looking at the Page the data-testid is company-name not company_name :)

```
title = r.html.find("div[data-testid=company-name]")
```

worked for me

Comment: Yeah that was a silly mistake. Btw what David said was the correct one coz I was wondering why the output from the website is just the styles and HTML tags